# Google Cloud Service Messages Saving Place

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm new to android development and I'm trying to implement a chatting feature in my application. for security issues, messages should be saved at my own database, not on third-party application database. I read here in stack overflow that GCM is a good option to be implemented in chatting-enabled applications, but my question is. where GCM saves messages? is it possible to make some configuration in its control panel to make it save messages in my database? or saving messages at google servers is a must? also is there any other way or third-party could be used in my case?

Comment: Try to make your question more specific, and include what you have tried so far.

Comment: GCM shouldn't be used as your main chatting mechanism, since it doesn't actually gurantee the message will be delivered.

Comment: Joe, I didn't try any code yet, as I'm not sure will it be useful or not, but I tried to read about GCM just to discover what is it and to find an answer to my question but I didn't find any thing. My question is, if it works fine in messaging, where does it save messages, data, photos, ... etc? is it on google servers? or I can put some server settings to it to save data on? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have read about GCM's **send-to-sync-notifications** already. They are what you are looking for if you do not want to send data to Google.

See [Simple Downstream Mesaaging - Collapsible Mesaages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages) for further information. Send such a notification to the device of a chat-message's recipient  and when receiving notification on the device just fetch the data from your own webservice and database and thats it. As long as you do not send any payload to Google-servers they cannot store your data.